# How can I work with a parameter that has a * in front of it in pyton?

Tags: python, function, class

I have a class `Com`

```
class Com:
    def __init__(self, a: float, b: float):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

and in the class this function:

```
def add(comp: "Comp", *comps: "Com") -> "Com":
```

with this input:

```
c1 = Com(5.0, 10.0)
c2 = Com(7.0, 100.0)
c_sum = Com.add(c1, c1, c2, Com(33.75, -14.25))
```

I don't understand how I can access the parameters of the add() function and work with them. Can someone explain it?

Comment: `comps` is a tuple of extra parameters passed to `add()` starting with the second one. You access it like a tuple. In order to help you more than that you'll have to post some kind of attempt to work with it so we could guide you further

Comment: @roeen30 Ok, but when I print the elements of the tuple I get `<__main__.Com object at 0x104497fd0>` how can I turn them into 'Com' class variables?

Comment: What else would you expect the object to show up as…?

Comment: They are not "class variables", they are instances of the `Com` class. This is how they are printed. If you want them to look differently, for example - showing the values of `self.a` and `self.b`, you need to implement a `__repr__()` method. Alternatively, you can create a dataclass which does this for you.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html